# pyinstaller 2.0 with pyqtgraph returns 6223 error invalid syntax

Tags: python, pyinstaller, pyopengl, pyqtgraph

I have been struggling to figure out why my program is not packaging with pyinstaller.  I have found the same error when I `import pyqtgraph` (http://www.pyqtgraph.org/). It uses pyopengl, so im not sure if that is the cause.

The error I get is:

```
File "D:\TMP\PyInstaller\depend\owner.py", line 118, in getmod
  co = compile(stuff.replace("\r\n","\n"),py[0], 'exec')
File "parallelizer.py",line 132
     self.progress = {ch.childPid: [] for ch in self.childs}

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Has anyone ran into this problem or has been able to package pyqtgraph or pyopengl? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you are using python 2.6; the line in question uses a dict comprehension, which is only valid syntax in Python 2.7 and 3.x.

You can easily fix this by changing the line to:

```
self.progress = dict([(ch.childPid, []) for ch in self.childs])
```

Comment: I got passed that error and now remoteproxy.py line 806
return {k: self._getProxyOption(k) for k in self._proxyOptions}
invalid syntax

Is this also a python 2.7 problem?  I downloaded the pyqtgraph 2.6, (or so I thought)

Comment: Yes. That is the same problem. You should switch to 2.7 if possible.